# How to remove myapp from stackapps?

Tags: discussion, stackapps

I have many apps in stackapps and I want to remove one of them.

I check https://stackapps.com/apps but failed.

Can any one guide me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to https://stackapps.com/

At right hand side there is option **Manage Your Applications**

and you will get list of your all the apps.

[image]